# Count occurrences of word in file

Tags: scala

Below code attempts to count the number of times "Apple" appears in an HTML file.

```
object Question extends App {

  def validWords(fileSentancesPart: List[String], wordList: List[String]): List[Option[String]] =
    fileSentancesPart.map(sentancePart => {
      if (isWordContained(wordList, sentancePart)) {
        Some(sentancePart)
      } else {
        None
      }

    })

    def isWordContained(wordList: List[String], sentancePart: String): Boolean = {

    for (word <- wordList) {
      if (sentancePart.contains(word)) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    false

  }

  lazy val lines = scala.io.Source.fromFile("c:\\data\\myfile.txt" , "latin1").getLines.toList.map(m => m.toUpperCase.split(" ")).flatten

  val vw = validWords(lines,   List("APPLE")) .flatten.size

  println("size is "+vw)


}
```

The count is 79 as per the Scala code. But when I open the file with a text editor it finds 81 words with "Apple" contained. The search is case insensitive. Can spot where the bug is ? (I'm assuming the bug is with my code and not the text editor!)

I've wrote a couple of tests but the code seems to behave as expected in these simple use cases :

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Stack;
import org.scalatest.FlatSpec;
import org.scalatest._;

class ConvertTes extends FlatSpec {

  "Valid words" should "be returned" in {

    val fileWords = List("this" , "is" , "apple" , "applehere")
    val validWords = List("apple")

    lazy val lines = scala.io.Source.fromFile("c:\\data\\myfile.txt" , "latin1").getLines.toList.map(m => m.toUpperCase.split(" ")).flatten

    val l : List[String] = validWords(fileWords, validWords).flatten

    l.foreach(println)

  }

    "Entire line " should "be returned for matched word" in {

    val fileWords = List("this" , "is" , "this apple is an" , "applehere")
    val validWords = List("apple")

    val l : List[String] = validWords(fileWords, validWords).flatten

    l.foreach(println)

  }


}
```

The HTML file being parsed (referred to as "c:\data\myfile.txt") in code above :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1TIppVWd0LSVG9Edl9OYzh4Q1U/view?usp=sharing

Any suggestions on alternatives to code above welcome.

Think my issue is as per @Jack Leow comment. For code :

```
  val fileWords = List("this", "is", "this appleisapple an", "applehere")
  val validWords = List("apple")

  val l: List[String] = validWords(fileWords, validWords).flatten

  println("size : " + l.size)
```

size printed is 2, when it should be 3

Comment: Just going through the code real quick, if a single line in the file contains the word "APPLE" twice, how is that counted?

Comment: @JackLeow I think this is indeed my issue, please see update

Comment: "(?i)apple".r findAllIn "this appleisApple an" size

Comment: In case your are looking for an alternative method.

Comment: s/sentance/sentence/g :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should do the following:

```
def validWords(
  fileSentancesPart: List[String],
  wordList: List[String]): List[Option[String]] =

  fileSentancesPart /* add flatMap */ .flatMap(_.tails)
    .map(sentancePart => {
      if (isWordContained(wordList, sentancePart)) {
        Some(sentancePart)
      } else {
        None
      }
    })

def isWordContained(
  wordList: List[String],
  sentancePart: String): Boolean = {

  for (word <- wordList) {
    //if (sentancePart.contains(word)) {
    if (sentancePart.startsWith(word)) { // use startsWith
      return true;
    }
  }
  false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions with a `Source` iterator:

```
val regex = "([Aa]pple)".r
val count = Source.fromFile("/test.txt").getLines.map(regex.findAllIn(_).length).sum
```